# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor does not trigger task

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to add a cross dag dependency using ExternalTaskSensor but haven't been able to get it to work. Dag A has `schedule_interval=None` as it doesn't have a fixed schedule and is triggered externally by a file creation event. Dag B should execute once Dag A has completed. Here is code for dag_a and dag_b.

**DAG A**

```
default_args = {
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.today()-timedelta(1),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'queue': 'default'
}

dag = DAG(
    'dag_a', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)

dag_a = AWSBatchOperator(
    task_id='dag_a',
    job_name='dag_a',
    job_definition='dag_a',
    job_queue='MyAWSJobQueue',
    max_retries=10,
    aws_conn_id='aws_conn',
    region_name='us-east-1',
    dag=dag,
    parameters={},
    overrides={})
```

**DAG B**

```
default_args = {
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.today()-timedelta(1),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'queue': 'default'
}

dag = DAG(
    'dag_b', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)

dag_b = AWSBatchOperator(
    task_id='dag_b',
    job_name='dag_b',
    job_definition='dag_b',
    job_queue='MyAWSJobQueue',
    max_retries=10,
    aws_conn_id='aws_conn',
    region_name='us-east-1',
    dag=dag,
    parameters={},
    overrides={})

wait_for_dag_a = ExternalTaskSensor(
     task_id='wait_for_irr',
     external_dag_id='dag_a',
     external_task_id=None,
     execution_delta = timedelta(hours=1),
     dag=dag,
     timeout = 300)

dag_b.set_upstream(wait_for_dag_a)
```

I set both dags with `schedule_interval=None` and same `start_date`. I even added `execution_delta = timedelta(hours=1)` for dag_b, but dag_b hasn't triggered so far, though dag_a is complete. Any help is appreciated.

I have tried using `TriggerDagRunOperator` which works, but is not suitable for my use case since dag_b will eventually be dependent on multiple parent dags.

Answer (score 0):

I've met similar problem before, so there are two things need to check, first I cannot see any time delta between DAG A and DAG B, both use the default arg so you should not give the waiting task a execution_delta, and for the airflow trigger, somehow it cannot detect the DAG finish sign if there are multiple parents DAGs, so I've tried give a value to external_task_id, like 'dag_a-done' instead of the default 'None', and that works. One more thing to mention is the task_id normally should not contain underscore.
The link is the source code of external sensor:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.html
Also an article describes how the ExternalTaskSensors works:
https://medium.com/@fninsiima/sensing-the-completion-of-external-airflow-tasks-827344d03142